# How to specify _id and array of Object Ids as a composite primary key in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, duplicates, composite-primary-key

In the MongoDB database, a Collection was created, and inserted with some data:

```
>>> db.createCollection("Restaurants")
>> { "ok" : 1 }

>> db.Restaurants.insert({ "_id": "coolDinings",
>> "AppliedParameters": [ ObjectId("5617a7a52da21a733547b8da"),
>> ObjectId("5617a5102da21a733547b8d9") ], "Review": "excellent    SeaFood", "Region": "USA" })
```

MongoDB default behaviour is to consider "_id" as the primary key.

However, I wanted a composite primary key consisting of the following fields:

- -1) "_id"
- -2) "AppliedParameters"

"AppliedParameters" is an array of ObjectIds that can really vary in terms of number of ObjectIds it stores which can range from 0 to around 20 or 30 ObjectIds.

I know the following code will create an index over both the aforementioned fields:

```
db.Restaurants.ensureIndex( { "_id": 1,"AppliedParameters": 1 }, { unique:true, sparse:true } );
```

However, my desire was to ensure that the aforementioned line of code will create a composite primary key.

In any case I ran the code.

In order to check if the composite key was created, I just reran the very first data insert again because I was hope it would complain by throwing an error related to composite primary key duplicates:

```
    >> db.Restaurants.insert({ "_id": "coolDinings",
    >> "AppliedParameters": [ ObjectId("5617a7a52da21a733547b8da"),
    >> ObjectId("5617a5102da21a733547b8d9") ], "Review": "excellent        SeaFood", "Region": "USA" })
```

However, it only gave the following error:

E11000 duplicate key error index: test.Restaurants.$*id* dup key: { : "coolDinings" }

The aforementioned error seems to indicate that the "_id" is duplicated.  I want the Mongo client to state something along the lines of duplicate composite primary keys are Not allowed.

How do I go about the said task?

Comment: Having an `_id` field that contains an array with up to 30 ObjectIds smells pretty bad. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thx.  I'm taking a different approach now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "composite" primary keys in mongodb (in a sense that they span multiple fields). `_id` is the one and only primary key.

If you want a complex primary key, composed of several pieces of data, insert them all into the `_id` field.

Note that `_id` value can't be an array (must be one of primitives or an object).

#### Can't do:

```
{ _id: [1, 2, 3] }
```

#### Can do:

```
{ _id: { a: 1, b: [2, 3] } }
```

Comment: _id filed can contains array, please have a look at this  db.collection.insert({_id:{"A":"B","C":["D","F"]},"status":"Hello"})

Comment: My objective was to help user to create the _id field which contains multiple field. nvm you updated your post.